# Does the using declaration allow for incomplete types in all cases?

Tags: c++17, undefined-behavior, incomplete-type, using-declaration

I'm a bit confused about the implications of the `using` declaration. The keyword implies that a new type is merely declared. This would allow for incomplete types. However, in some cases it is also a definition, no? Compare the following code:

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

struct box;

using val = std::variant<std::monostate, box, int, char>;

struct box
{
    int a;
    long b;
    double c;
    
    box(std::initializer_list<val>) {
        
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(val) << std::endl;
}
```

In this case I'm defining val to be some instantiation of variant. Is this undefined behaviour? If the using-declaration is in fact a declaration and not a definition, incomplete types such as box would be allowed to instantiate the variant type. However, if it is also a definition, it would be UB no?

For the record, both gcc and clang both create "32" as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've not included [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer), I'm attempting a non-lawyer answer.

Why should that be UB?

With a `using` delcaration, you're just providing a synonym for `std::variant<whatever>`. That doesn't require an instantiation of the object, nor of the class `std::variant`, pretty much like a function declaration with a parameter of that class doesn't require it:

```cpp
void f(val); // just fine
```

The problem would occur as soon as you give to that function a definition (if `val` is still incomplete because `box` is still incomplete):

```cpp
void f(val) {}
```

But it's enough just to change `val` to `val&` for allowing a definition,

```cpp
void f(val&) {}
```

because the compiler doesn't need to know anything else of `val` than its name.

---

Furthermore, and here I'm really inventing, "incomplete type" means that some ***definition*** is lacking at the point it's needed, so I expect you should discover such an issue at compile/link time, and not by being hit by UB. As in, how can the compiler and linker even finish their job succesfully if a definition to do something wasn't found?

Comment: I understand the difference between declaration and definition for functions. But when do I essentially _define_ a type using `using`? I always thought that defining a class means fixing the memory layout of the class which I suppose is happening in the above case?

Comment: No, `val` is incomplete because `box` is incomplete. The memory layout of `val` is not known before you define `box`. Indeed, if you try `sizeof(val)` before you define `box`, it fails at compile time, and the compiler tells you exactly that the type is incomplete.